# Finding \$L\$ value in simple circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc

Hello and first of all sorry for posting a screen, I don't know how to make my own schematics.

[image]

This is one of the excersises from previous year's electrotechnics. The formula to calculate the result is already derived.

$$T = \frac{L}{R_{t}}$$
However, may I ask, how to find the
\$L\$
value in this circuit? Because it's not stated in the task's description...

Thanks

Comment: On EE.SE use the `\$` tag for inline MathJAX. Your screengrab is fine but can create your own using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all: when we've a shirt circuit we know that the resistance (in the switch) is equal to \$0\space\Omega\$ so the resistor \$\text{R}_\text{l}\$ is not important and we can ignore it.

Assuming that the source (that you've put as a current source instead of a voltage supply) is a constant voltage supply of \$100\space\text{V}\$. We can write (according to [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)):

$$-\text{E}\left(t\right)+\text{I}(t)\cdot\text{R}_\text{t}=-\text{I}'(t)\cdot\text{L}\tag1$$

For the initial condition, we have:

$$-\text{E}\left(t\right)+\text{I}_\text{open}(t)\cdot\text{R}_\text{t}+\text{I}(t)_\text{open}\cdot\text{R}_\text{l}=-\text{I}_\text{open}'(t)\cdot\text{L}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{I}_\text{open}(t)=\frac{1}{1001}\cdot\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{100100t}{\text{L}}\right)\right)\tag2$$

So, when \$t=30\cdot10^{-6}\$:

$$\text{I}_\text{open}(30\cdot10^{-6})=\frac{1}{1001}\cdot\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{100100\cdot30\cdot10^{-6}}{\text{L}}\right)\right)\tag3$$

So, substituting your values we get:

$$\text{I}(30\cdot10^{-6})=20\cdot10^{-3}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{L}\approx0.156224\space\text{H}\tag5$$

Comment: Isn't it necessary to take into account that there is a current flowing through L and RL before the switch closes?

Comment: @Linkyyy, wait let me revisit my answer (indeed :))

Comment: I'm afraid you can't ignore the 100 kOhm resistor, as it causes already 1 mA to flow before the switch gets closed. That's 5% of the 20 mA at 30 microsecond. Too much to ignore for an accurate answer if you ask me.